# How should I inject into provider?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to inject service/provider into my provider but it seems like I cannot do it the same way with factory or service? Please tell me what I did wrong, I know it's simple and probably just a stupid mistake but I cannot findout

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/B1XGDZNOpiIJVE4q3zMP?p=preview

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Michael, you cannot inject dependencies into provider this way. You can provide your dependencies in get method

```
this.$get =['$window', 'alert', function (window, alert){
}];
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help Chandermani, got it working now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. Provider will be registered during the configuration phase. And in this phase the services are not yet available for injection. See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module - **Module Loading & Dependencies**

Also checkout http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers. There you will see what is available during configuration phase.

Comment: hi @Mchael, so in my case I should just fall back to using factories instead? Or can I perhaps inject into the $get function somehow?